# Can I use a 'wildcard until matched' in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a db with XML in it. I'm looking for records like:

```
select * from TABLE t
where data like '%<parent id="someID">???<perm aid="someValue" myperm="_" inherit="_">0</perm>???</parent>%'
```

I've filled in `???` where I'm actually looking for a wildcard that ignores anything until it matches the next part of the statement.
I'm afraid it can't be done but I'm asking anyway to be sure...

Comment: I suspect you want `regexp_substr()` (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm), but it is hard to tell exactly what you are looking for.  Can you edit your question with some actual values that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just want `%`, which will allow any number of characters (including zero).

If the requirement is actually more complex than that, @Gordon Linoff's suggstion to use `regexp_substr()` is probably your best option.

Comment: Sadly `%` also matches Childnodes with different Parents.

Comment: This is definitely a regex issue then. You might want to consider rephrasing the question to make the problem you're trying to solve more clear and adding the regular expressions tag.